# `[MKAnnotationView setBounds:]` has performance degragation problem on iOS SDK 15

Tags: ios, performance, mapkit, mkannotationview

- I created a customized annotation view by extending `MKAnnotationView`, and overriding the `[MKAnnotationView setImage:]` method.
- When the `[MKAnnotationView setImage:]` method is called, `[MKAnnotationView setBounds:]` is called, and thus `[MKAnnotationView _metricsDidChange]` and some other methods are called.
- I see that `[MKAnnotationView _metricsDidChange]` is the bottleneck for the performance problem.
- While in SDK 14, there is no such method called.

Attach the time profile screenshot below:

SDK14:
[image]

SDK15:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Temp fix

I searched but with no luck to find any official materials.

Finally, I found a workaround to make sure the SDK will not call `[MKAnnotationView setBounds:]` in `[MKAnnotationView setImage:]` method:

- **set the `MWAnnotationView`'s frame (using the image size) before setting the image to it.**

Home this helps.